# Keep last N items and remove other items from ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox-control

I have a C# Winform with a ListBox.  I am trying to remove all the items except the last 5 items. The ListBox sort is set to Ascending.

The items in the ListBox look like the following:

```
2016-3-1
2016-3-2
2016-3-3
2016-3-4
...
2016-03-28
```

Here is my code to remove the beginning items.

```
for (int i = 0; i < HomeTeamListBox.Items.Count - 5; i++)
{
    try
    {
        HomeTeamListBox.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

I've also tried `HomeTeamListBox.Items.RemoveAt(HomeTeamListBox.Items[i]);`

Comment: the code is correct, what is the problem?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani The code is not correct. It bypasses some items. For example the item which is at index 1 will not be removed using this code. The OP removes item at index 0, then items goes up and the item which previously was at index 1, now is at index 0. So when the OP tries to remove item at index 1, unexpectedly he will see the item which was at index 2 at start, is removed and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there are more than `n` items in the list, you should remove items from start of the list.
This way you can keep the last `n` items of [`ListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8):

```
var n = 5; 
while (listBox1.Items.Count > n)
{
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reza , that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your index i is going to increase by one each time it loops, but you are going to be removing an element each time you loop. What you want to do is remove each element at index 0 for the first 5 passes. So using your current For Loop

HomeTeamListBox.Items.RemoveAt(HomeTeamListBox.Items[0]);

Is what you want in the body.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you;

```
if(HomeTeamListBox.Items.Count > 5)
{
    var lastIndex = HomeTeamListBox.Items.Count - 5; 
    for(int i=0; i < lastIndex; i++)
    {
       HomeTeamListBox.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = HomeTeamListBox.Items.Count-5; i>=0; i--)
{
    HomeTeamListBox.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```